# Dropdown menu not showing from scraped website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on scraped webpage (i have been allowed to scrape it by the owner) and for some reason, the dropdown on the page isnt working.All the CSS/JS/images are linked properly, but as much as i tried and tried, the dropdown isnt working.
I am sure i got the HTML and CSS properly, and linked everything, so the only thing i can think of is some kind of JS error, and im not quite familiar with JS :\

HTML is :

```
<ul id="nav">

  <li class="level0 nav-1 first active level-top parent"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Formal Shirts</span></a>

    <ul class="level0">
      <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first"><a href="#"><span>Regular Fit</span></a></li>
      <li class="level1 nav-1-2 last"><a href="#"><span>Semi-tailored Fit</span></a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>

  <li class="level0 nav-2 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Ties</span></a></li>

  <li class="level0 nav-3 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Cufflinks</span></a></li>

  <li class="level0 nav-4 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Casual Shirts</span></a></li>

  <li class="level0 nav-5 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Knitwear</span></a></li>

  <li class="level0 nav-6 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Polo Shirts</span></a></li>

  <li class="level0 nav-7 last level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Hoodies &amp; Tops</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

And CSS is (i think i copied it all):

```
#nav { margin: 0px auto; width: 1012px; height: 62px; background: url('bg_nav.png') no-repeat scroll center top rgb(255, 255, 255); }
#nav li.parent {  }
#nav li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; }
#nav li a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
#nav li a span { display: block; white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer; border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px 31px; line-height: 13px; }
#nav li.last a span { border-right: 0px none; }
#nav li ul a span { white-space: normal; padding: 0px; border-right: 0px none; line-height: 25px; }
#nav li { float: left; }
#nav li a { float: left; font-family: futurastdmedium; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; padding: 13px 0px; }
#nav li a:hover { color: rgb(206, 211, 247); }
#nav li.over.parent a:hover, #nav li.active.parent a:hover { color: rgb(36, 35, 75); }
#nav li.active.parent a #nav li.over ul a, #nav li.active ul a { background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; }
#nav ul, #nav div { position: absolute; width: 15em; padding: 10px 0px; top: 39px; left: -10000px; background: url('bg_trans.png') repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgb(102, 102, 102); }
#nav ul li { float: none; }
#nav ul li.last { border-bottom: 0px none; }
#nav ul li a { float: none; padding: 0px 29px; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(36, 35, 75) ! important; }
#nav ul li a:hover { color: rgb(146, 149, 190) ! important; }
```

I uploaded my "version" of the site to http://goo.gl/nEAQ7c, and the original is here http://goo.gl/s3aWwi and working properly.
If anybody can give me some advice, that would be great.Moderators, if i crossed some rules, im sorry.

Comment: Please don't use short links. Since you included your code, can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: check your console. There are some access errors: **...is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: Mooseman, there is at least 25 JS files included, at 6-7 .css file, i dont know which part to paste on Fiddle :\ 
PeterVR, im a JS noob, i saw several errors on Chrome Inspector, but they arent telling me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your css

```
#nav li:hover ul.level0{
   left: 0px;
   z-index:500;
}
```

Then it should work.

Other than that I don't know why it isn't